# PyQt5 + Qt Designer. Как подключить событие к элементу?

Tags: python, qtcreator, pyqt5, pyqt

Недавно начал пробовать разбираться со связкой PyQt5 + Qt Designer. Имеется окно, которое открывается, в окне есть QMenu. Хочу обработать событие, связанное с нажатием на один из пунктов меню (Open File). Искал, пробовал - не выходит. Я не совсем могу понять что и как происходит в других примерах. Вопрос достаточно легкий для знающих людей, надеюсь найду тут подробные ответы.

[image: Скрин дизайнера]

[image: Структура файла]

```
info - личный класс, не играет особой роли
main - класс самого окна
py_mainForm - класс для работы с с контролами
ui_mainForm - файл из дизайнера
```

(попутно небольшой вопрос на счет логичности разделения между main и py_mainForm)

**py_mainForm**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import info


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('ui_mainForm.ui', self)


    def set_onClick_menu_open(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', 'C:\\', 
        'TXTfiles (*.txt)')

        q = QMessageBox(self, 'qqq', fname, QMessageBox.NoButton)
```

**main**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from py_mainForm import MainWindow

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

mw = MainWindow()
mw.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если через дизайнер: у вас на скриншоте в нижнем правом углу есть **Редактор Сигналов/Слотов**. В нем необходимо сигнал от пункта меню (например, `triggered`) связать со слотом обработчика (например, слот `showMaximized()` главного окна) Вы можете создать свой слот, реализующий какие-то действия. Этот просто для примера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что автоматически генерируется в `mainwindow.ui`:

```
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>actionOpen_file</sender>
   <signal>triggered()</signal>
   <receiver>MainWindow</receiver>
   <slot>showMaximized()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>-1</x>
     <y>-1</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>199</x>
     <y>149</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
```

Возможно, для понимания лучше посмотреть на аналогичный пример без дизайнера.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        bar = self.menuBar()

        menu = bar.addMenu('Menu')
        act = menu.addAction('Open_file')
        act.triggered.connect(self.showMaximized)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = MainWindow()
    m.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, за последний час использования гугла, я продвинулся уже довольно далеко в понимании, но еще не до конца.
например(ui файл):
     <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
     <action name="actionOpen_file">

как я могу обратиться к actionOpen_file из .py файла?

Comment: `self.menuBar.children()` - вернет список из `QToolButton` и `QMenu`. Выбираете нужное вам меню, у него вызываете `actions()` - получаете список всех пунктов этого меню. Например: `self.menuBar.children()[-1].actions()[0]`

Comment: к menuBar я могу обратиться лишь как к методу, иначе выдает ошибку о том, что объект не имеет атрибутов "children"
Если обращаюсь как к методу, то ругается на connect (нет такого атрибута)

     self.menuBar().children()[-1].actions()
     [0].actionOpen_file.connect(self.set_onClick_menu_open())

Comment: `self.menuBar().children()[-1].actions()[0]` - уже возвращает объект `QAction`. Т.е. `actionOpen_file` тут лишнее. А вообще, вам лучше остановиться дебаггером в конструкторе `MainWindow` и просмотреть, что возвращает каждая часть из всего длинного выражения, чтобы не копировать такие однострочники бездумно.

Comment: проблема была, потому что в во время тестов убрал то, о чем вы говорили в начале, прошу прощения. Все работает, большое спасибо )